# Writing an Algorithm in Pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I am having a hard time with writing pseudocode.

Question:
Consider an array A[1..n], where n>= 3. Write an algorithm (using pseudocode) that computes the minimum value among all the elements with index a multiple of 3 (e.g. A[3], A[6], A[9], …so on).

```
for i=1 to A.length
    while n>= 3
       A[n] = A[n*i]
```

I took an attempt at writing the code. Can somebody provide some insight on what I have written.

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: The thing about pseudocode (or how I use pseudocode) is that everything goes. You don't worry too much about syntax, you just try to bring an idea across. This question is not about pseudocode, it's about having no clue how to solve the problem.

Comment: So basically as long as the idea is correct there can be many ways to write pseudocode?

Comment: Yes.  The point of pseudocode is that you no longer need to worry about a computer understanding what you mean; it's now a person, and people are much better at understanding ambiguity.

Comment: Hmm ok, that makes more sense. I was thinking that there was one and only one way of solving it. Tthank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this

```
min = A[3]    
for i=3 to A.length
    if min > A[i]
       min = A[i]
    i += 3
```

Comment: It should be `if min > A[i]`.